# Is there way to see the floating licence server details in install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

we are using install4j to build the app installer.
when building the installer we are getting **not able to communicate with licence server**.

Here is the logs :

*[Step 1/3] [INFO] install4j version 5.1.6 (build 5598), built on 2013-06-12 [06:04:46] :     [Step 1/3] [INFO] Loading configuration [06:04:46] :     [Step 1/3] [INFO] There was an error communicating with the license server. [06:04:46] :     [Step 1/3] [INFO] The application will now quit.*

Is there a way we can see the licence server details from the install4j installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your license server running? You can check that with the bin/admin tool in the installation directory of the license server and by checking the log/server.log file.

Also, there may be a firewall in between that prevents a TCP connection from the install4j compiler to the license server on port 11862, either for outgoing connections on the machine where install4j is running or for incoming connections on the license server.

Comment: I dont have licence server details. it may be the enterprise one. even the license server details are not configured in the pom.xml. I think it would have been updated with --licence=KEY parms in install4j installation. just want to know is there a way we can read the licence key from install4j compiler. if there is no way then i can talk to licensing team to get those details.

Comment: The license key for a floating license server is saved in the file license.txt in the installation of the license server. The IP address or the host name of the license server can be seen in $HOME/.install4j8/config.xml in the licenseKey element on the machine where you run the install4j compiler.